# What is the upper limit on the number of Sidekiq workers we can have?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

I am new to sidekiq, my requirement is that there can be as many high priority jobs as the number of users logged into the system. Lets sat each user is expecting a notification soon as his job is processed.

I have one sidekiq daemon running with concurrency of 50 so at a time I can have just 50 jobs processing? I have read that the [wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment) states we should have multiple sidekiqs running.

1. What is the upper limit on the number of sidekiqs to run?
2. how will I be able to match the number of users logged in with the number of concurrent workers?
3. Is there a technology stack I can use to launch these workers? Something like unicorn to have a pool of workers? Can i even use unicorn with sidekiq ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the upper limit on the number of sidekiqs to run?

You will want a *max* of one Sidekiq per processor core. If you have a dual-core processor, then 2 Sidekiqs. However, if your server is also doing other stuff such as running a webserver, you will want to leave some cores available for that.

> how will I be able to match the number of users logged in with the number of concurrent workers?

With Sidekiq, you pre-emptively create your threads. You essentially have a thread-pool of X idle threads which are ready to deploy at any moment should a huge surge of jobs come in. You will need to create as many threads as the max number of jobs you think you will have at any time. However going over 50 threads per core is not a good idea for performance reasons (the amount of time switching between a huge number of threads [significantly cuts into the CPU time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34582442/276949) allocated for the threads to do actual work).

> Is there a technology stack I can use to launch these workers? Something like unicorn to have a pool of workers? Can i even use unicorn with sidekiq ?

You can't use Unicorn for this. You need some process supervisor to [handle starting/restarting](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#daemonization) of Sidekiq. Their wiki recommends Upstart or systemd, but I've found that [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) works incredibly well, and is really easy to set-up.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. I'm 4 points less to be able to upvote aparently    but i wont miss it :)

Comment: Thank you too, this helps me a lot =).